# Tense in imperative sentence

Tags: reported-speech

My question is :The officer said to the peon ,"Let the boy come in".

Its indirect speech: Option 1-The officer ordered the peon to let the boy come in.
                                   or
                   Option 2-The officer ordered the peon to let the boy came in.

if option 1 then why the form of come does not change.

Comment: "The officer ordered the peon to let the boy came in" is wrong. Whether in direct or reported speech, the form of the verb following 'let' is the base (infinitive) form. Let the boy come. Let the bird fly. Let the children play. Let the old man sleep.

Comment: Please don't answer questions in comments. This by passes the voting system of the site. Comments should be used to suggest improvements and ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The verb in **the boy *come* in** there will always be the bare/plain/unmarked infinitive.

> Let him **breathe**.
>
> Let her **come** in.
>
> Let them **tell** us the facts.
>
> Let her **tell** us the facts.

Comment: because "let" must be followed by a non-finite verb or clause.